# Convert POM pages from cheezy page-object to site-prism gem

Tags: ruby, parsing, text-parsing, page-object-gem, site-prism

I want to be able to easily convert page classes/methods and methods from the cheezy page-object gem for Ruby to the site-prism gem. Doing this manually will take more time, so I wanted to know if anybody implemented something that does this for you. If no existing repo meets this criteria, then any suggestions on what to use for making my own parser in this case?

Any other suggestions are welcome! Thank you in advance

Gem References:
https://github.com/cheezy/page-object

https://github.com/site-prism/site_prism

I have done some pages manually using the replace functionality of my IDE. The syntax of both of the gems is very similar, but different enough that it takes a significant amount of time to convert a single page.

I've looked up any existing parsers that would convert the Ruby files - found nothing.

Comment: Would is be an option uninstalling `page-object` gem and deleting its files and then installing `site-prism` and generating all page objects with it from your source files?

Comment: That's an option yes. I would be removing the page-object gem and replacing it with site-prism. I do want to generate the site-prism page objects from the existing cheezy page-object gem page objects. My question is about how I would do that efficiently because there are many pages and page sections that need to be converted. If I misinterpreted, please let me know. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I realized that using Chat GPT to parse for me is a possible avenue. And then I can polish up any mistakes myself